# what is the valid RDL schema for SSRS 2008r2 reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I know that  SSRS 2008 rdl schema is located at

http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition

but what is the valid url for SSRS 2008 R2 schema.

They have added new element Report Section in SSRS 2008 R2 , so there must be a new schema which validates that and other newly added features.

I am not able to find it.

Also can someone create ssrs-2008R2 tag and associate it with this question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2008R2 url is http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition